# Javascript: best way to search for numbers in comma delimited strings

Tags: javascript, string, search, numbers

I couldn't find an answer. hopefully someone will be able to help.

I need to be able to search for numbers like "12" and only get 1 true on a comma delimited string like:

```
var str = "1, 13, 112, 12, 1212, 555"
```

Basically, if I have product codes, and I find a 12, I'd like to return a SINGLE "Bicycle" due to the singe "12". But I'm getting a lot of false hits with the numbers 112, 1212 etc.

Any ideas what function or method I could use?

Comment: do you need just to check, it the value exist, or the index of the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split the string and then `Array.includes` to check whether the value exists in the array or not.

```js
function check(str, val){
  return str.split(", ").includes(val+"");
}

var str = "1, 13, 112, 12, 1212, 555"

console.log(check(str, 12));
console.log(check(str, 121));
console.log(check(str, 1212));
```

Comment: Wow... that was fast!! Thanks. I'm going to digest this and see if I can include it in my google sheet. Thanks again.

Comment: Marked it as correct. I should have prefaced by saying this was for a google sheet. I wasn't able to get it to work in google sheets, and after researching it, I think the includes() function is not supported... something to do with server side processing.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer  :

```js
var twelve = /(^| )12(,|$)/;
var s = "1, 13, 112, 12, 1212, 555";
console.log(twelve.test(s)); // true
```

### About the regular expression

Following your comment, let me give you a little help to understand the first line.

`/(^| )12(,|$)/` is a regular expression. A regular expression is a sequence of characters that defines a search pattern. This is one of the features embedded in JavaScript, but it's not inherently linked to JavaScript. In other words, you should not learn regular expressions in the scope of JavaScript, but JavaScript remains a good way to experiment on regular expressions. That being said, what does `/(^| )12(,|$)/` mean ?

The two `/` are delimiters indicating the boundaries of the expression. What's in between the `/` is the expression itself, `(^| )12(,|$)`, it describes the pattern we are looking for. We can classify the various characters involved in this expression into two categories :

- regular characters (`1`, `2`, `,` and ),
- metacharacters (`(`, `)`, `|`, `^` and `$`).

Regular characters are characters with no special meaning. Example :

```
/cat/.test("cat") // true
/cat/.test("concat") // true
```

Metacharacters are characters with a special meaning :

- `^` means "beginning of the text",
- `$` means "end of the text",
- `()` indicates a subexpression,
- `|` indicates a logical OR.

Example 1, empty text :

```
/^$/.test("") // true
/^$/.test("azerty") // false
```

Example 2, exact match :

```
/^zert$/.test("zert") // true
/^zert$/.test("azerty") // false
```

Example 3, alternatives :

```
/(az|qw)erty/.test("azerty") // true
/(az|qw)erty/.test("qwerty") // true
```

To wrap it up, let's come back to `/(^| )12(,|$)/` :

```
(^| )   start of the text or " "
12      then "12"
(,|$)   then "," or end of the text
```

Thus, our pattern matches with strings like `12`, `* 12`, `12,*` or `* 12,*`, where `*` means "zero or more characters".

Last word, in JavaScript you can declare a regular expression using the `new` keyword :

```
var twelve = new RegExp("(^| )12(,|$)");
```

This is useful when you need to change some part of the expression dynamically :

```
function newNumberPattern (n) {
  return new RegExp("(^| )" + n + "(,|$)");
}

var eleven = newNumberPattern(11);
var twelve = newNumberPattern(12);
```

That's it, I hope this is enlightening :-)

Comment: Thanks!! I need to bone up on your first line :)

Comment: @Thonex1234 I updated the answer with a couple of details about "the first line" :-)

Comment: Wow... thanks so much for this. It does look a lot like Klingon... that's a nice feature! :)  I have some weekend boning up to do! Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think .includes() isn't supported on google sheets. But this seems to work:

```
    /**
@customfunction
*/
function AK_CHECK(input){
    var split_cell = input.split(",").indexOf("12");
    if (split_cell > -1){
        return "Bicycle"
        } else {
        return "NO"}
        }
```